# Sobolev estimates $\|\phi\|_2\leq\|\phi\|_{H^2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I have been reading the paper 'Convergence of a finite volume scheme for a system of interacting species with cross-diffusion' by Carrillo et al. in Section 4.1 they have been using an estimate,

$\|\nabla\phi\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}\leq \|\phi\|_{H^2(\Omega)}$,

which seems quite intuitive, however I am unable to show the result. I already know for a bounded domain, $\Omega$

$\|\cdot\|_{L^1(\Omega)}\leq\|\cdot\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$,

and this can be extended to any finite $p$. However, this is not true for the essential supremum norm. $\|\cdot\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\nleq\|\cdot\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}$, as pointed out by @falcon

I also unsuccessfully tried to use the Poincaré Inequality, stated as
$\|\phi\|_{L^p}\leq\|\nabla\phi\|_{L^p}$, for $\phi$ in $H^2(\Omega)$.

---

**EDIT:** This assertion is false as shown by the counterexamples provided by @falcon. I am posting a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472299/sobolev-estimates-nabla-phi-2-leq-c-phi-h2) with the correct form as given by @calvin-khor

Comment: You want to show $||\phi||_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}\leq ||\phi||_{H^2(\Omega)}$ for a bounded $\Omega$ ?

Comment: Yes, that this what I would like to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is not true. Take $\Omega = [0,1/2]$ and $\phi(x) = 2$ for all $x$, then
$$\|\phi\|_{L^\infty} = 2$$
but
$$\|\phi\|_{H^2} = \left(\|\phi\|_{L^2}^2 + \|\phi'\|_{L^2}^2  + \|\phi''\|_{L^2}^2\right)^{1/2} = \int_0^{1/2}2 = 1. $$

---

**EDIT:** Still not true. Take $\Omega = [0,1/2]$ and $\phi(x) = 2x$, then
$$\|\nabla \phi\|_{L^\infty} = 2$$
but
\begin{align}
\|\phi\|_{H^2} &= \left(\|\phi\|_{L^2}^2 + \|\phi'\|_{L^2}^2  + \|\phi''\|_{L^2}^2\right)^{1/2}  \\
&= \left(4\int_0^{1/2} x^2 dx + 4\int_0^{1/2} dx\right)^{1/2}\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{6}+ 2\right)^{1/2} < 2.
\end{align}

Comment: I think I wrote the inequality wrong, I am sorry I will fix it.

Comment: What I would like to show is $||\nabla\phi||_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}\leq ||\phi||_{H²(\Omega)}$ for a bounded domain $\Omega$

Comment: What is true is $\|\nabla \phi\|_{L^\infty((a,b))} \le C \|\phi\|_{H^2((a,b))}$.

Comment: May be they missed the constant or its in the estimate, should I post this as a seperate question? Btw thank you for the counterexamples!

Comment: Yes, post another question with the link to this one. And you are welcome for the counterexamples :)

Comment: Just added a new one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472299/sobolev-estimates-nabla-phi-2-leq-c-phi-h2). @Falcon