# Sobolev estimates $\|\nabla\phi\|_{\infty}\leq C\|\phi\|_{H^2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

This is in continuation to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472225/sobolev-estimates-phi-2-leq-phi-h2).

What I want to prove is

$\|\nabla\phi\|_{L^{\infty}((a,b))}\leq C\|\phi\|_{H^2((a,b))}$

Comment: $L^2$ on the left hand side? Are you sure? This is different from the linked question, and trivially true with $C=1$

Comment: No, its should be $L^{\infty}$, my bad. Fixed it.

Comment: It directly follows from the estimate $\|\phi\|_{L^\infty(a,b)} \le c \|\phi\|_{H^1(a,b)}$.

Comment: Of course, but then how do I do that one. May be this is trivial for you. But I need to see a proof at least once. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prove it for $I = \mathbb R$ and for all $1 \le p < \infty$ (in your case just take $p = 2$), the general case follows from the extension theorem. The aim is to show that
$$\|u\|_{L^\infty(I)} \le C \|u\|_{W^{1, p}(I)}$$
for some $C$ depending only on $I$ (not on $p$). Let $v\in C^\infty_0(I)$ and set
$$G(s) = |s|^{p - 1} s.$$
By setting $w = G(v)$ (which is in $C^\infty_0(I)$), we get (exercice)
$$w' = G'(v) v' = p|v|^{p-1}v'.$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
G(v(x)) &= \int_{-\infty}^x p|v(x)|^{p-1}v'(x)dx
\end{align}
by Holder we get
\begin{align}
|v(x)|^p &\le p \|v\|_{L^p(I)}^{p-1}\|v'\|_{L^p(I)}
\end{align}
and by Young inequality
\begin{align}
|v(x)| &\le C\|v\|_{W^{1, p}(I)}
\end{align}
for all $v \in C^\infty_0(I)$. Note that $C$ does not depend on $p$ as $p^{1/p} \le e^{1/e}$ for all $p \ge 1$. We deduce the desired result by density.

**Remark.** This shows that the inclusion $W^{1,p}(I) \subset L^\infty(I)$ is continuous for all $p \in [1, \infty]$ (the case $p = \infty$ is trivial). Moreover, when $I$ is bounded, we may show that
$$W^{1,p}(I) \subset C(\overline{I})$$
is compact for $1 < p \le \infty$.

Comment: Thank you! i found this in Brezis!

Answer (score 1):

Another way using the Fourier transform. By the Fourier inversion theorem and the integral formula of the Fourier transform
$$
\|\nabla\varphi\|_{L^\infty(\Bbb R)} = \|\mathcal{F}\big(x\,\widehat{\varphi}\big)\|_{L^\infty(\Bbb R)} \leq \|x\,\widehat{\varphi}\|_{L^1(\Bbb R)}
$$
and by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$\begin{align*}
\|x\,\widehat{\varphi}\|_{L^1(\Bbb R)} &\leq \|(1+x^2)^{-1/2}\|_{L^2(\Bbb R)}\, \|(1+x^2)^{1/2}\,x\,\widehat{\varphi}\|_{L^2(\Bbb R)}
\\
&\leq \pi\, \|(1+x^2)\,\widehat{\varphi}\|_{L^2(\Bbb R)} = \pi\, \|\varphi\|_{H^2(\Bbb R)}
\end{align*}$$
using the fact that $\|(1+x^2)^{-1/2}\|_{L^2(\Bbb R)} = \int_{\Bbb R} (1+x^2)^{-1}\,\mathrm d x = \pi$ and the fact that $x\leq (1+x^2)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Although this is more elegant, I would need some knowledge of Fourier transforms to understand this. Which is not an unreasonable assumption to make, however I am quite rusty with that at the moment. Thank you!